# Tomcat does not listen on configured JMX port

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jmx

On my Windows 10 PC I try to get JMX working on my local Tomcat9 installation which I start via Netbeans.
I added this line to `catalina.bat`

> set CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"

but without success. `netstat /an` does not show port 9000 listening and of course I can't connect using VisualVM.

When I check the local tomcat in VisualVM, I can see that my options are used though.
[Tomcat overview in Visual VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUVNI.png)

What am I missing to get access to JMX? Any hints are highly welcome.

Harry.

Comment: Might be a windows firewall problem.  Can you attach to Tomcat with visualvm with the MBeans plugin installed, and see the beans?

Comment: Yes, with the plugin I can see MBeans. I doubt that it is any firewall issue since I can not even see the port listening with `netstat`. It should at least be there if the firewall would prevent connections.

Comment: I finally found my mistake! The problem are the quotes around the arguments. That somehow does handle it as one argument instead of many. The solution is to use:
`set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`

Comment: Ah, Windows behaves different from Unix in this regard.  Glad you found it.